# How to mock instance attribute of django form

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm doing a unit test where I'm mocking a Django form, but I'm having some trouble because I need to mock two things from the form:

- An instance attribute (`token`)
- A method (`is_valid`)

I'm using the form in a view, importing it like this:

```py
from profiles.forms import PaymentForm
```

And I have tried the following to mock it:

```py
    @patch('profiles.forms.PaymentForm')
    def test_when_processing_a_payment_then_the_event_is_tracked(self, payment_form_class):
        payment_form_class.is_valid.return_value = True
        payment_form_class.cleaned_data = {'token': 1}
```

This approach does not work, `is_valid` returns false.

```py
    @patch('profiles.forms.PaymentForm')
    def test_when_processing_a_payment_then_the_event_is_tracked(self, payment_form_class):
        payment_form_class.return_value.is_valid = True
        payment_form_class.return_value.cleaned_data = {'token': 1}
```

This neither.

I'm using Django and unittest. I have successfully mocked the `is_valid` with a helper function of our code base, but it does not seem to work with instance attributes. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You might need to mock the form on where it is used in your view since it's already imported there before your mock runs. So something like: `my_app.my_views.PaymentForm`

Comment: Lol it was that, I always forgot the correct path in the patch, Thanks! Pls post it as an answer :)

Comment: Sure! Posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to mock the form on where it is used in your view since it's already imported there before your mock runs.

So something like:

```
@patch('my_app.my_views.PaymentForm')
```